# SpringBoot - HelloWorld

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a simple hello world app with SpringBoot where localhost:8080/welcome.html will show us Hello World.

I think I did all good but I can't see HelloWorld, just Whitelabel error page.

This is the link to my repo. If someone could check what is wrong I will be very happy!
https://github.com/BElluu/ElenXHello

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springbelluu</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springboot-helloworld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

SpringbootHelloworldApplication.java

```
package com.springbelluu.springboothelloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootHelloworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootHelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
package com.javainuse.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
    public ModelAndView firstPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

Comment: Post your code in the question itself.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._"

Comment: I am not sure if this is your issue but have you tried just making the endpoint "/welcome" instead of "/welcome.html". I am not a pro when it comes to spring boot but I am not sure if you can actually map to `*.html`.

Comment: This is because of the package structure of your application. Your controller is in a completely different package, `com.javainuse.controllers`, than your application class which is in package `com.springbelluu.springboothelloworld`. Make sure the controller is in the same package or a subpackage of the app class, otherwise Spring is not going to find it. Or else add a `@ComponentScan()` annotation to the application class that refers to the package that contains the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters if you want to get starter with Spring Boot I strongly suggest **NOT** to use JSP. There are quite [some limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) when using JSP, one of them is it doesn't work with jar packaging. Secondly it is a dated technology and doesn't receive much attention/updates anymore apart from keeping if functional in newer JEE versions. It is better to use something like [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/).

Next you are using snapshots versions for a version of Spring Boot that already is at `2.1.3.RELEASE` (at the moment of writing).

That being said change your `pom.xml` to the following (fix version, remove JSP stuff and replace with Thymeleaf).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springbelluu</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springboot-helloworld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**NOTE:** Because you now use a final version you don't need all the repositories in your `pom.xml` anymore!.

Now delete your JSP and create a `welcome.html` in `src/main/resources/templates/`. (You can actually remove your `webapp` directory in full.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome! Spring Boot for ElenX</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The setup you now have is more modern and easier to work with then JSP.

In your `application.properties` remove the `spring.mvc.view` properties as Spring Boot will automatically configure Thymeleaf with correct settings.

Answer (score 0):

@BElluu ... your main application and Controller class are in different packages so componentscan is not working ...just check package level

```
package com.springbelluu.springboothelloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootHelloworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootHelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }
}


package com.javainuse.controllers;  
 // use this package package com.springbelluu.springboothelloworld;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
    public ModelAndView firstPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to below link by Spring Framework to create brand new Springboot Project:

https://start.spring.io/

or

1.**Create a simple web application**

Now you can create a web controller for a simple web application.

src/main/java/hello/HelloController.java

package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}
```

}

2. **Create an Application class**

   ```
   Here you create an Application class with the components:

   src/main/java/hello/Application.java

    package hello;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }

     @Bean
     public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
       System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

       String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
       Arrays.sort(beanNames);
           for (String beanName : beanNames) {
               System.out.println(beanName);
            }
         };
       }
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Here is SpringBoot Main class file Noting Changed Here.  
    -----------------------------------------

    package com.Encee.SpringBoot_HelloWorld;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }

     }

    Here is controller package class 
    -----------------------------------------
    package com.Encee.SpringBoot_HelloWorld.controller;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController

    public class Controller {
        @RequestMapping("/hello.html")
       public String hello() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    -----------------------------------------        
    Now Main file run as Java Application will get your output.
     SCREEN SHOT
```

Comment: Please review [the stack overflow formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

Your issue has been fixed you can view the changes at my commit.

https://github.com/farooqrahu/ElenXHello/commits/master

Comment: While this might be the answer, pleae provide it in the answer itself instead of only providing a link.

Comment: This is not a valid answer, this is best as a comment.